# add single binary to PATH

Tags: bash, path

Maybe this is a WSL question, in which case I'm not sure where to ask.

I have a single binary that I want to add to path `~/.scry/bin/scry`. So I went to `~/.bashrc` and added

```bsh
export PATH="$HOME/.scry/bin/scry:$PATH"
```

The reason I don't want to add the folder is because `~/.scry/bin` has some other binaries that I don't want in my PATH.

I did that and then run:

```bsh
~$ . .bashrc
```

But when I run `scry` (the binary) I get a `command not found` error.
I tried restarting the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and opening it again (debian). But it still doesn't recognize the command.

I'm unsure of how to proceed, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't work -- the paths from `PATH` will be treated as directories to be prepended to commands no matter if they're executables or any other kind of file.

A simple solution is to create a directory somewhere else, create a symbolic link to your binary there, then add that directory to `PATH`:

```
mkdir ~/my-bin
ln -s ~/.scry/bin/scry ~/my-bin
PATH=$PATH:~/my-bin
```

Answer (score 8):

```bsh
hash -p "$HOME"/.scry/bin/scry scry
```

Adding the above to your `.bashrc` file will tell your interactive shell that `scry` is located at `"$HOME"/.scry/bin/scry`.

Other ways of doing something similar involves creating an alias with

```bsh
alias scry="$HOME"/.scry/bin/scry
```

or a shell function with

```bsh
scry () {
    "$HOME"/.scry/bin/scry "$@"
}
```

The `PATH` variable contains a `:`-delimited list of *directories* that will be searched when a command that hasn't yet been used is given. Adding the pathname of a utility to the `PATH` variable will therefore not really do anything.